# Not "On the Rocks"

Tags: colloquialisms

I walk into a bar and order a drink.  The bartender may ask me:
*Do you want that on the rocks?*
I usually respond *"Yes"* or *"No"*

Is there a colloquial expression for *not on the rocks?*

Comment: I can certainly answer this one. straight up.

Comment: +1's all around. This also led me to research what a ["whiskey sour, straight down"](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/474:_Turn-On) is, but it turns out to just be a [subatomic pun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark#Table_of_properties).

Comment: I'd almost swear I once heard a bartender tell me that they used the phrase "on the rails", but I can't (after a very cursory search) find a use of it.

Comment: `neat` is the answer, of course. It sounds much more proper/refined/classy than `straight` too.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Although *straight* is used, that can also simply mean unmixed with anything else, but it can be chilled with ice.

The unambiguous word would be **neat**, meaning no ice and no other drinks mixed in.

See also [this cocktails.about.com link](http://cocktails.about.com/b/2007/05/31/is-it-neat-or-straight-up.htm) for a short explanation:

> **Neat** typically refers to a undiluted shot of liquor served at room temperature.
>   **Up** or **Straight Up** is usually used to describe a drink that is chilled with ice (shaken or stirred) and strained into a glass (typically a cocktail glass). 
>   **Straight** is where things get really confusing because drinkers use it in two different ways. Some use [it] when they order a straight pour of darker spirits (e.g. bourbon straight, which would mean neat) while some use it to mean a white spirit chilled and served in a cocktail glass (e.g. vodka chilled, which would mean up).

Comment: Huh, OK. I would never use _straight_ for anything that was adulterated in any way, ice included. I wonder if that's regional.

Comment: I am quite sure it is regional. Just to be sure I usually specify "no ice", unless I _know_ that they know what _neat_ means. But it's tough nowadays getting a decent dry martini... so I never assume too much :)

Comment: neat just means no water in it .. why mention that one?  this is about ice right?

Comment: actually i see what you mean. I better go sober up :)

Comment: Just a little kicker: if you're ordering a margarita, your alternative to "on the rocks" is probably "frozen", i.e. like a slushie... however, I think that's an exception, rather than a useful rule.

Comment: You have a typo (missing the second 'c') in your hypertext for the cocktails.about.com link. The URL is find though, so the link works.

Answer (score 8):

Well, the classics are *straight* in its sense of (from the [online Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/straight)):

> free from extraneous matter :  unmixed <straight whiskey>

and *neat*, [defined](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neat) by the same source as

> free from admixture or dilution :  straight <neat brandy>

Neither is particularly colloquial but both are perfectly common, idiomatic English.

Comment: @oerkelens _straight whiskey_ does not contain ice and woe the barman who would dare put ice in my requested _straight Caol Ila_. I was just adding _neat_ while you were writing that comment though :).

Comment: Bars overcharge for good whiskey so I prefer to have it at home. And the missus knows better than to put ice in it, whether I ask for it straight, neat or otherwise — provided I ask it nicely :)

Comment: Ila needs ice to cut the damned peat smell (runs back to the east coast :) )

Comment: @JoeBlow run fast ;). And Caol Ila is the least peaty of all the Islays.

Comment: you could be right terdon, a fine point.  i recommend glenfarclas as a complement if you come over to the Other Side

Answer (score 3):

"Off the rocks". I've heard it as a joke quite a few times, and I suppose any barman would understand that request.

Comment: 'off the rocks, neat' will cover you.

Answer (score 2):

Straight and neat are synonyms for drinks. Typically I have seen/heard neat used for colored alcohols and straight for clear alcohol.

Personally, I always use "neat".

Answer (score 2):

Neat is what you say when ordering a whiskey without ice.

From Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+neat

> (of liquid, especially liquor) not diluted or mixed with anything else.
>
> "he drank neat Scotch"
>
> *synonyms*:   undiluted, straight, unmixed; *informal* straight up "neat gin"

Comment: This means ordering a whiskey without water, though I suppose the end result is the same if you leave it for long enough...